# Please correct this Javascript Code? to go to URL from form

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

Firstly Thanks to Dev Chen & sideroxylon for Answering my previous problem. Im almost near the solution but its not working out...?

In the Following Code we get values1 & Value2 from User & when He presses The GO Button It goes to

```
 http:// foo.com/document/ value1 / value2 /pageview.html
```

This Code is OK! Its giving an Alert but when I change it to goto URL its not working in my hands please give it a look?

http://jsfiddle.net/rxnXd/1/

HTML

```
A: <input type="text" id="value1"/><br />
B: <input type="text" id="value2" /> <br />
<input type="button" value="GO!" onclick="redirect()" />
```

Javascript

```
function redirect() {
alert("Set window.location to:http://www.foo.com/document" + document.getElementById("value1").value + "/" + document.getElementById("value2").value + "/printview.html");
```

}

( Here is the Old Question http://goo.gl/x85m6H )

Its giving and Alert ... How to Change it so it goes to the URL.

Its Alert function how to make it goto the calculated Link?

Comment: The alert `Set window.location to http://...`. It's litertally telling you what you need to do. Have you tried doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

`window.location.href = newUrl;`

Your `redirect` function can be changed as:

```
function redirect() {
    window.location.href = 'http://www.foo.com/document/' 
        + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("value1").value)
        + '/'
        + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("value2").value)
        + "/printview.html";
}
```

Comment: function redirect() {
     window.location.assign("http://foo.com/doc/" + document.getElementById("value1").value + "/" + 

document.getElementById("value2").value + "/printview.html");
}

Comment: @IsaacQassim You can also use `assign` as well. Both works. However make sure that you are using `encodeURIComponent`. Just take my function as is, it will work. (I fixed the typo in the first part btw)

Comment: Thanks its working BTW whats advantage of using encodeURI? that User may enter  @##)(^@$@#?? and they are incoded properly?

Comment: @IsaacQassim Yes, some characters have to be properly encoded, such as the `?` character and `encodeURIComponent` will do it for you. Do not forget the accept the answer ;) Thanks!

Comment: I surly did that Scripting is really Interesting!